# Classes with different functions inside

Tags: python, function, class

I have this code, and I want to get the final result, in this case, the average.

Of course, the task that I have to do is more complex.

```
class data:
    def __init__(self, Num1, Num2, Num3):

        self.Num1 = Num1
        self.Num2 = Num2
        self.Num3 = Num3

    def sum_fun(self):

        self.total = self.Num1 + self.Num2 + self.Num3

        return total

    def average (self):

        avg = self.total / 3

        return avg
```

And I would like to call data, given my parameters, and the class should give me the average

```
print(data.sum_fun(1,2,3))

>>>2
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your example throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: And `return total` should be `return self.total`

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance to call an instance method.

sum_fun() accepts no parameters, and classes should always start with capital letter. Variables should not

```
print(Data(1,2,3).sum_fun())
```

> the class should give me the average

You'd want that to look like this, since you shouldn't rely on the user to call sum_fun before the average.

```
def sum_fun(self):
    return sum[self.num1, self.num2, self.num3])

def average(self):
    return self.sum_fun() / 3
```